# How to default database value when system date change

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm currently doing a banking website for my project, using C# and asp.net. One of the function is 'Remaining Daily Limit'. I need the database value to change back to default once I changed the system date to another day. Example : If a user had $500 (default value) as a daily limit, and he used all up. The next day, he will have $500 again. May I know how should I go about it?

Comment: Can you share what your database schema looks like, what tables you have etc. Also what have tried so far?

Comment: This sounds more like a database design question than C#, but I guess it depends on how you implement it. You could add a column to whatever customer table you have that says what their daily limit; then you could keep a table of transactions. If you subtract their summed transactions for the current day from their daily limit, then you will know how much spending value the customer has left. I'm not sure this is enough to count as an answer so I'm putting it as a comment. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a SQL script that will create how I would setup your db with some sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE tblBankCustomer
(
    BankCustomerId INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    , FirstName NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
    , LastName NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
    , DailySpendingLimit DECIMAL(38, 2) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_tblBankCustomer_DailySpendingLimit DEFAULT(500)
)

CREATE TABLE tblTransactionType
(
    TransactionTypeId INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    , TransactionType VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)

INSERT tblTransactionType (TransactionType)
VALUES ('Deposit')
    , ('Withdrawal')

CREATE TABLE tblTransaction
(
    TransactionId INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    , BankCustomerId INT NOT NULL
    , TransactionDate DATE NOT NULL
    , Amount DECIMAL(38, 2) NOT NULL
    , TransactionTypeId INT NOT NULL
)

ALTER TABLE tblTransaction
ADD CONSTRAINT FX_tblTransaction_tblBankCustomer
FOREIGN KEY (BankCustomerId)
REFERENCES tblBankCustomer(BankCustomerId)

ALTER TABLE tblTransaction
ADD CONSTRAINT FX_tblTransaction_tblTransactionType
FOREIGN KEY (TransactionTypeId)
REFERENCES tblTransactionType(TransactionTypeId)

INSERT tblBankCustomer
(
    FirstName
    , LastName
)
VALUES ('Jeremy', 'Pridemore')
    , ('K', 'YQ')

INSERT tblTransaction
(
    BankCustomerId
    , TransactionDate
    , Amount
    , TransactionTypeId
)
VALUES
    (1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 48.50, 2) -- Jeremy, Today, $48.50, Withdrawal
    , (1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 300.00, 2) -- Jeremy, Today, $300, Withdrawal
    , (1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, -200.00, 1) -- Jeremy, Today, $200, Deposit
    , (2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 285.00, 2) -- K, Today, $285, Withdrawal
    , (2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 215.00, 2) -- K, Today, $215, Withdrawal
GO
CREATE FUNCTION fGetRemainingSpendingLimit
(
    @BankCustomerId INT
    , @Date DATE
)
RETURNS DECIMAL(38, 2)
BEGIN
    SET @Date = ISNULL(@Date, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

    DECLARE @RemainingLimit DECIMAL(38, 2) =
    (SELECT
        SUM([Transaction].Amount)
    FROM tblBankCustomer Customer
    INNER JOIN tblTransaction [Transaction]
        ON [Transaction].BankCustomerId = Customer.BankCustomerId
        AND [Transaction].TransactionDate = @Date
    INNER JOIN tblTransactionType TransactionType
        ON TransactionType.TransactionTypeId = [Transaction].TransactionTypeId
        AND TransactionType.TransactionType = 'Withdrawal'
    WHERE Customer.BankCustomerId = @BankCustomerId)

    RETURN @RemainingLimit
END
GO

-- Some sample selects
SELECT dbo.fGetRemainingSpendingLimit(1, NULL)
SELECT dbo.fGetRemainingSpendingLimit(2, NULL)
```

Then in C# you should know the customer's ID for the customer you're working with. If you're using somethiing like ADO.NET you can call this function directly and use the value in code.

Comment: hi, but may I know which part is it to auto reset the value when I change the system date ?

Comment: @KYQ Sorry to not answer you question, I missed getting on SO yesterday. Using this technique you don't need to explicitly reset their value for a different date. You store 1 value, how much they're supposed to get to use per day, and you store their transactions. Then you calculate how much the remaining usage is for a given day.

Answer (score 0):

Default values are *usually* stay in some config file. In your specific case, I would say that you can

- or have a `table` with default values
- or in the `tables` where is possible to have *restore* functionality have *default column* with corresponding values.

after, can restore them using some `stored procedure`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create SQL job and schedule it to run every midnight, within the job you can execute a stored procedure reseting values to $500.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, based on that there may be other requirements in the future, I'd have a table that looks like:

```
UserID    AppliedOn    Limit
1         1/1/2012     500
1         2/1/2012     750
```

This give you a historic view of limits, that you can give to the user or data-mine.  In the same way, that is how I would apply current daily limits.

```
UserID    AppliedOn    Withdrawn
1         1/10/2012    125
1         1/10/2012    225
```

Now on 1/1/2012 it would be easy to determine what the amount left in the limit is without any jobs or triggers.  And again you'd have historic values that can be data-mined for other features.

```
SELECT
  ul.Limit - uw.Sum as LimitLeft
FROM
  UserLimit ul
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
      UserID,
      AppliedOn,   
      SUM(Limit) as Sum
    FROM
      UserLimit
    Group by
      UserID,
      AppliedOn) uw on ul.UserID = uw.UserID
                       and ul.AppliedOn = uw.AppliedOn
WHERE
  ul.UserID = @userID 
  AND ul.AppliedOn = @dateInQuestion
```

(my raw SQL skills might be a bit rusty due to Entity Framework here).